# Linux RAW Socket Error - How to get the correct MTU to use after a send failure?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have an application that is using `sendmsg()` on a RAW socket.  My application uses the `IP_HDRINCL` socket option, as it sets up the IP header.

I set the `DF` bit in the egress packet to 1 (don't fragment).

Here is what I want to do next... When the Kernel tries to send the packet, it's looking up the route entry for the destination, and it gets the `MTU` to use for that host from the entry (sometimes lower due to `PMTU` discovery).

When I try to send a larger packet, the `sendmsg()` call fails, and the error code is `"message too big"`.

What I now want is to figure out in the application what the `MTU` should actually be.  I have been trying to use the ancillary data.  I set `IP_RECVERR` in the socket options, and then called `recvmsg()` on the same send file descriptor with the `MSG_ERRQUEUE` flag set, but that call fails.

Is this the correct path to take?  I am reading in the man pages that the ancillary data behavior differs for different socket types.  Does this work for RAW?

Or is there a better Kernel API to get the correct `MTU` from the route entry?